# Error check: Suppose that $(y^2+2xy) dx$-$x^2 dy$=0 has an integrating factor that is a function of $y$ alone $[i.e., μ = μ(y)]$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $(y^2+2xy) dx$-$x^2$$dy$=0 has an integrating factor that is a function of $y$ alone $[i.e., μ = μ(y)]$. Find the integrating factor and use it to solve the differential equation.

For this one, I get the integrating factor $\mu$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt y}$, which is correct.

Then I multiply the integrating factor with the original equation, $\frac{2y}{\sqrt y}$$dx$+ $\frac{x+y}{\sqrt y}$$dy$=$0$

Next I try integrating both sides since the ODE is separable, get
$\int \frac{2y}{\sqrt y}$$dx$+$\int \frac{x+y}{\sqrt y}$$dy$=$0$

And the result is$\frac{2y}{\sqrt y}$$*x$+$x*(\sqrt y)$+$\frac{2}{3}$*$y^{\frac{3}{2}}$=$F(x,y)$=$C$. But doesn't match the answer.

The correct answer is $\frac{2y}{\sqrt y}$$*x$+$\frac{2}{3}$*$y^{\frac{3}{2}}$=$F(x,y)$=$C$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's Bernouilli's equation are you sure about the solution of the book ?

Comment: oops, I realize that my answer is right, just need to simplify a little. I looked up the wrong question and found the wrong answer. Sorry guys, problem solved.

Comment: no problem Beacon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Bernouilli's equation.
$$(y^2+2xy) dx-x^2dy=0$$
$$y^2dx+y dx^2-x^2dy=0$$
Integrating factor $\mu (y )=\dfrac 1 {y^2}$
$$dx+\dfrac {y dx^2-x^2dy}{y^2}=0$$
$$dx+d\left (\dfrac  {x^2}{y} \right)=0$$
$$x+ \left( \dfrac {x^2}{y} \right)=C$$
Are you sure it's the right equation and solution ?

Comment: The solution is $2x  \sqrt y$+$\frac{2}{3}$$y^{\frac{3}{2}}$=$C$

Comment: For which equation ? The one you posted has not that solution. @Beacon